# How to pass unknown command line arguments containing special characters (bash)?

Tags: bash, unix, passwords, command-line-arguments, special-characters

I am trying to figure out how to solve a problem with a "$" causing command expansion as part of a password field. How do you backslash the "$" when using command substitution (unknown) arguments? (i.e. $1, $2)

For example, in a script called 'testPass':

**PASSWORD="$1"**

**echo $PASSWORD**

If I type in:

**testPass abcd123#$asd**

Then the output is:

**abcd123#**

I have also tried single quotes (echo '$PASSWORD') as most people say online, however this just prints:

**$PASSWORD**

I have even tried using the printf command, which has also been mentioned online, as so:

**printf '%q\n' '$PASSWORD'**

However this does something similar, with the following output:

**\$PASSWORD**

I have searched for a long time to figure this out, however I am new to UNIX so I could be missing something I am unaware of. Please let me know if you have any ideas, thank you.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1106761/harold) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1106764/harold). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379190/58455

Answer (score 2):

Your $1 assignments and 'echo' commands are working just fine. ($variables are only expanded once – if the expanded value has something that looks like another variable, that is *not* expanded again.)

The problem is that the missing `$asd` part never reaches the script to begin with.

The interactive shell command line performs variable expansion in exactly the same way as shell scripts do. When you type `abcd123#$asd`, the `$asd` part acts as a variable name and is expanded to (in this case) an empty value before the whole "testPass" command even runs.

So what you should quote is the command-line arguments themselves:

- Variable expansion never happens inside single quotes:

  ```
  echo 'The password is abcd123#$asd'

  testPass 'abcd123#$asd'
  ```
- Variables *are* expanded inside double-quotes, or when there are no quotes at all, but this can be avoided by escaping the `$`:

  ```
  echo The password is abcd123#\$asd

  testPass "abcd123#\$asd"
  ```